# Using Angular 2 & Spring Boot & PL/SQL without JPA

Tags: angular, spring-boot, plsql

Good day, I am a back-end developer and currently learning Angular for front-end. In my job, we have to work with a huge amount of data. Unfortunately, in JPA using Oracle PL/SQL is difficult(Procedures, Functions). For this reason, I must not use JPA for working with a huge amount of data in the database. Instead of JPA, I use pure JDBC(using Connection, PrepareStatement, and ResultSet for calling Oracle procedures). However, I have difficulties with "Update, Delete" operations on Angular when I am using Rest API with pure JDBC and Angular.

There some code of working operations(Create, Read) :

```
 @PostMapping("/employees") // create operation
 @ResponseBody
 public String insertEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
   JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
   Connection conn = null;
   CallableStatement cs = null;
   try {
     String firstName = employee.getFirstName();
     String lastName = employee.getLastName();
     String emailId = employee.getEmailId();
     conn = hds.getConnection();
     cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL NERS.EMPLOYEE_INSERT_P(?, ?, ?)}"); // calling procedure from Oracle
     cs.setString(1, firstName);
     cs.setString(2, lastName);
     cs.setString(3, emailId);
     cs.executeUpdate();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
     DataBase.close(cs);
     DataBase.close(conn);
   }
   return json.toString();
 }

@GetMapping("/employees") // read operation
 public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployee(Model model) {
   ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   try {
     conn = hds.getConnection();
     ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM NERS.EMPLOYEE"); // selecting data from Oracle
     ps.execute();
     rs = ps.getResultSet();
     while (rs.next()) {
       Employee e = new Employee();
       e.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("employee_id"));
       e.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
       e.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
       e.setEmailId(rs.getString("email_id"));
       employees.add(e);
     }
     model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
     DataBase.close(rs);
     DataBase.close(ps);
     DataBase.close(conn);
   }
   return employees;
 }
```

But, I have problems with "Update, Delete" operations when I am using Angular for front-end, before it worked with pure HTML(Thymeleaf framework)

```
 @PutMapping("/employees/{employeeId}") // update operation
  @ResponseBody
  public String updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try {
      int employeeId = employee.getEmployeeId();
      String firstName = employee.getFirstName();
      String lastName = employee.getLastName();
      String emailId = employee.getEmailId();
      conn = hds.getConnection();
      cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL NERS.EMPLOYEE_UPDATE_P(?, ?, ?, ?)}"); // calling update procedure
      cs.setInt(1, employeeId);
      cs.setString(2, firstName);
      cs.setString(3, lastName);
      cs.setString(4, emailId);
      cs.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      DataBase.close(cs);
      DataBase.close(conn);
    }
    return json.toString();
  }

  @Deletemapping("/employees/{employeeId}") // delete operation
  public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int employeeId) {
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try {
      conn = hds.getConnection();
      cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL NERS.EMPLOYEE_DELETE_P(?)}"); // calling delete procedure
      cs.setInt(1, employeeId);
      cs.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      DataBase.close(cs);
      DataBase.close(conn);
    }
    return "employees";
  }
```

In Angular front-end there are not mistakes, I checked them with JPA. Only at the back-end, I have problems. Please can you advise some links of tutorials or your advice? I will be happy with it. I am looking this problem within 2 weeks. Thank you for advance.

Comment: Hi,

You have shared your controller code but not described about exact problem you are facing. Do you want to know how to organize code when you are using pure JDBC for database operations ?

Comment: Hello, as I said, Create and Read operations are working, my all logic estimated in this class. I have a problem with Update and Delete operations, My Update and Delete operations are taking ID of Employee but, they are not executing.

Comment: Is your procedures are getting executed for update and delete?

Comment: Yes I checked them in my database, also they are working on pure HTML(without Angular), the problem is I can not use these operations with REST APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I found a solution for my problem, the problem was on REST API URLs.